# is it possible to start smartphones rear camera using jquery or javascript and read the data

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, camera

how can we start the camera using j query or java script and read data same as apple and android applications .

i want to create qrcode scanner same as android apps with webpage when i click on button then camera will open and read the AVCaptureMetadataOutput for decoding the codes.

but i dont know where to start ? i just wanted to open camera and and start reading the result while camera is open so i can use captured data of screen and use base64 data to  decode the qrcode

please help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050717/how-can-i-generate-barcode-or-qr-code-as-a-image-programatically-in-android

Comment: @tejshah i need to create it in web application . it means when i click on my webpage then mobile camera will start itself